# Code won't run when loaded

Tags: php, html

Can anyone see where I have messed up please ?

the output I am looking to achive is to have a box 78 pixels x 78 pixels and for each pixel have a link to another page, at the moment only the 1st pixel works.

The code loads on the page and can been seen under the image, how is this happings ?

```
   <html>
<head>

<title>Untitled Page</title>

<style type="text/css">
#ImageMap1
{
   border: 0px #000000 solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_ImageMap1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:600px;height:600px;z-index:0;">

<img src="images/black.bmp" id="ImageMap1" alt="" usemap="#ImageMap1_map" border="0" style="width:600px;height:600px;">

<map name="ImageMap1_map">
foreach ($string){
    $x = 1; $y = 1; $z = 1;$output = '';
    for($x=1;$x<79;$x++)
    {
    for($y=1;$y<79;$y++)
    $string = $x .','.$y.','.$z;
    $output .= '<area shape="circle" coords="'. $string . '" href="./index.html" target="_blank" alt="" yellow="">'
    }
    }
    echo $output;

</map>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eer i added a php tag.. but is this NOT php?

Comment: Looks like PHP to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in the php tags

```
<?php
foreach ($string){
    $x = 1; $y = 1; $z = 1;$output = '';
    for($x=1;$x<79;$x++)
    {
    for($y=1;$y<79;$y++)
    $string = $x .','.$y.','.$z;
    $output .= '<area shape="circle" coords="'. $string . '" href="./index.html" target="_blank" alt="" yellow="">'
    }
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added Code as just plain text, let it get executed by php, add php tags.

If php tags are present, then only server knows to execute it and process, else it is considered plain text.

So use like this:

```
foreach ($string){
$x = 1; $y = 1; $z = 1;$output = '';
for($x=1;$x<79;$x++)
{
for($y=1;$y<79;$y++)
$string = $x .','.$y.','.$z;
$output .= '<area shape="circle" coords="'. $string . '" href="./index.html" target="_blank" alt="" yellow="">'
}
}
echo $output;
```